# PowerApps User always sees prompt "is available for offline use"

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a user who launches the powerapps app and then opens an app within the app and always sees the app "is available for offline use" message. Other users who use the same version of powerapps and same app do not see this.  There is nothing special in the app savedata, loaddata, etc. that would be optimized for offline use so am puzzled why this user sees this message.

[image]

Comment: Are they using same browser and desktop application?

Comment: They are using the mobile powerapps application on their iphone.  Oddly enough now I observe it on my android phone as well.  The apps data connection is to a sharepoint list and this pops up after we hit a screen which shows a gallery of the items in the list.